# Passing javascript date to rails form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

At the top of a page I have a javascript datepicker. The selected date is stored in the variable `newDate`

Lower I have a form in rails like so:

```
<%= form_for(@checkin) do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

I want the date selected above to get passed as a parameter upon form submission. I want to do something like this:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :checkedin_at, :value => newDate %>
```

But I'm pretty sure I can't mix client-side and server-side code like this. Is there another way to pull this off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a hidden field like you did, and from javascript you can set the value of that hidden field to the actual value.

#### Erb part:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :checkedin_at, :value => '', :id => 'date' %>
```

#### Javascript part:

```
document.getElementById('date').setAttribute('value', newDate);
```

You can do javascript set part when you got the new date value or on submit it's your decision.

#### Modifying

If you want to modify an already saved `checkedin_at` variable later, then you need to read it before. So you may need to set the actual value in Erb from the model, and read with:

```
newDate = document.getElementById('date').getAttribute('value');
```

#### Sidenote

It's a good idea to do it in an unobtrusive way with javascript. To Be prepared for browsers without javascript support on people with disabilities who cannot use normal browsers.

So a simple HTML solution is a nice to have with visible date field with parsable (not a timestamp) date field.

Comment: Thanks. I removed the `:value => ''` in the Erb line and it now seems to work in cases where the checkin is new, and also when editing an existing checkin.

Answer (score 0):

on submit, u will have to copy the data field data to the hidden field and then submit the form. but if u want to submit the selected date when the form is submitted, its better to have the date as a visible and selectable field of the form.